# How can $valid of a form element be accessed in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't manage to access $valid of a form element.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    testForm: {{testForm.testmail.$valid}} <!-- NOTHING APPEARS HERE -->

    <form name="testForm">
        <input type="email" name="testmail">
    </form>
</body>
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/tqVEFohBFBxkkD7WPLTt?p=info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you havent set an `ng-model` to your input. If no model is set then Angular cannot validate your field

```
<input type="email" name="testmail" ng-model="testmail>
```

This is your updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BKdLp0x4tQUy6I9sK2rS?p=info)

[More on ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) and how vital it is for AngularJs

Comment: add this to it {{testForm.testmail.$valid && testForm.testmail.$dirty}}